# Can I change the class of my Aurora RDS Reserved Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-billing, aws-reserved-instances

Currently I have a `db.r5.2xLarge` RDS Reserved Instance (Aurora Postgres).

I'm thinking about moving to `db.r6g.2xLarge`, if I do that will my reserved instance discount still apply?

I looked up on AWS documentation but coudn't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

RDS offers **size-flexible** reserved instances, which allow you to change the size within a [class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html) (e.g. r5.2xlarge -> 2* r5.xlarge), but they need to [stay within a class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithReservedDBInstances.html#USER_WorkingWithReservedDBInstances.SizeFlexible:%7E:text=Size%2Dflexible%20reserved%20DB%20instances%20can%20only%20scale%20in%20their%20instance%20class%20type.%20For%20example%2C%20a%20reserved%20DB%20instance%20for%20a%20db.r5.large%20can%20apply%20to%20a%20db.r5.xlarge%2C%20but%20not%20to%20a%20db.r6g.large%2C%20because%20db.r5%20and%20db.r6g%20are%20different%20instance%20class%20types.).

Because of this, that wouldn't apply to your modification. The other (bigger) problem is that Aurora is not in the list of supported DB Engines for this:

> Size-flexible reserved DB instances are available for the following Amazon RDS database engines:
>
> - MariaDB
> - MySQL
> - Oracle, Bring Your Own License
> - PostgreSQL
>
> — [Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithReservedDBInstances.html#USER_WorkingWithReservedDBInstances.SizeFlexible)

**tl;dr:** The discount **won't apply** anymore if you go through with your proposed change.

Comment: You're welcome :) - The way to show that an answer helped you is to upvote (if you have sufficient reputation points) and accept it (the little checkmark next to the score). That's sufficient - thanks comments besides that aren't necessary (but I appreciate it).

Answer (score 0):

Size-flexible reserved DB instances are available for the following Aurora database engines:

Aurora MySQL

Aurora PostgreSQL

[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_WorkingWithReservedDBInstances.html)